# how to change month in date.valueOf

Tags: java, date

i would like to know to change only the value of month in Date.valueOf for example:

```
    Date startDate = Date.valueOf("2020-01-18");
```

how do i change only the month value of startDate after creating that Date object in java?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [the `Date` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html)?

Comment: user85421 it dosent work..

Comment: The Date class has no valueOf() method.

Comment: java.sql.Date does have a valueOf() method. Don't use it unless you are in a JDBC context.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `LocalDate.parse("2020-01-18").with(Month.AUGUST)`.

Comment: @Ole I believe I clearly wrote to not use it and to go for the new time package... it is up to OP which to use (if there is a choice) ((and sure it was deprecated for **a reason**))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this

```
Date startDate = new GregorianCalendar(2020, 0, 18).getTime(); //(year, month - 1, day)

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate );
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);// change to month you want 
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse( "2020-01-18" )
.withMonth( 4 )
.toString()
```

> 2020-04-18

## Details

Both of the terrible classes `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

For your input, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2020-01-18" ) ;
```

Change the month. The *java.time* classes use immutable objects. So we get a fresh new `LocalDate` rather than alter the original.

```
LocalDate ldApril = ld.withMonth( 4 ) ;
```

> ldApril.toString(): 2020-04-18

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]